# Zend form with a middle step, how to modify the normal code

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How would one go about having a multi step type form with zend. This is what I'm trying to do..

Normally I have a form, the user fills the form. When the form is submitted (post) AND is valid, I do the final action (add to the database or anything else).

```
public function indexAction(){
   $form = new Application_Form_Test();

   if(form is valid){
      //do the final thing.. add to the database or whatever
   }
   $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

What I want to do is insert a middle step. When the user submits the form, I don't want to insert into the database right away. I want to first calculate some additional data, show the calculated data to the user in addition to the input he just entered, and display a confirm button. If the user presses submit, I do the final thing which is add to the database, otherwise I cancel out of the whole operation. So can someone think of a simple way to do this without doing a lot of crazy hacking?

Comment: The general idea is to collect data and store it in session until you're ready to commit. The guide [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html) is quite verbose but should give you an idea

Comment: Have a look at multi page forms at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prepared a draft of a possible way to overcome your problem. Basically it involves two actions (indexAction and index2Action) and a session.

**indexAction**

```
public function indexAction() {
    $form = new Application_Form_Test();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {

            // calculate some additional data
            $calculatedData = someCalulations();

            // if form is valid than save submitted and calculated data in a session
            $addAccInfoNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('data');
            $addAccInfoNamespace->postData = $form->getValues();
            $addAccInfoNamespace->calculatedData = $calculatedData;
            $addAccInfoNamespace->lock();

            // and redirect to the second stage (or middle stage)
            return $this->_redirect('index/index2');
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

**index2Action**

```
 public function index2Action() {

        // retrieve data saved in the first stage (indexAction).
        $sessionData = new Zend_Session_Namespace('data');

        if (null === $sessionData->postData || null === $sessionData->calculatedData) {
            // if no data go to index, or throw execption or whatever.
            return $this->_redirect('index/index');
        }

        // get the data
        $oldPostData = $addAccInfoNamespace->postData;
        $calculatedData = $sessionData->calculatedData;

        // form that only shows cunfirmation button
        // However, if you want to show data in this form, that you need to 
        // populate Application_Form_Test2 with whatever data you want.
        $form = new Application_Form_Test2();


        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {

                if (!$form->confirm->isChecked()) {
                    // if confirm submit button was NOT clicked go to e.g. index
                    // This may mean that ,e.g. cancel submit button was click.
                    return $this->_redirect('index/index');
                }


                //do the final thing.. add to the database or whatever


                // don't need this session namespace anymore
                Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('data');

                // and redirect to e.g. success confirmation page
                return $this->_redirect('index/success');
            }
        }

        // show confirmation button and additional calculated data
        $this->view->calculatedData = $calculatedData;
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
```

What do you think?

Comment: Wow, it's like we shared brainspace for a few minutes there :)

Comment: @Phil Brown. I noticed :-). But it is good. It suggests that this is a way to do what OP tries to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd do it...

1. Create two controller actions, let's call them "stepOneAction" and "stepTwoAction".
2. stepOneAction would instantiate and validate your form (on POST). On successful validation, store the form data (`$form->getValues()`) in a session namespace then redirect to stepTwoAction
3. stepTwoAction would then pull the form data out of session, do the calculations and pass it all to the view for display. The view would also contain a small form (can be a `Zend_Form` or just done in markup only) with two buttons ("Confirm" and "Cancel") that submits to stepTwoAction.
4. Also in stepTwoAction, check for a POST request, clear the session namespace, check the button pressed and then act accordingly.

Some extra considerations

- stepOneAction should probably clear out the session namespace on a normal GET request
- Both forms should probably contain some CSRF protection using Zend_Form_Element_Hash